# MVC4 - Display upload progress for each file while uploading multiple files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload, asynchronous

I'm building an mvc 4 application that makes file uploading. When I get HttpPostedFileBase range, I get streams on them and pass to my business logic layer to save them and bind with database records. This is done without any problems. But when displaying current state of uploading progress comes in, I'm a bit confused. I make a second request while an uploading runs, but it waits for first request to be executed completely.

I know that in same browser client instance (actually same session), my requests are synchronized. But there is a solution that I read about, asynchronous actions.

To try asynchronous actions, I used `Stream.CopyToAsync(..)` instead of `Stream.CopyTo(..)`. I'm also using `Task.Delay(10000)` to simulate file uploading progress. Then while **asynchronous** UploadFile action runs, I invoked **synchronous**  UploadProgress on same browser instance. Result is still waiting for first request to complete. Below is the code I use. Where am I wrong?

Here is async action to upload files;

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(PFileUploadModel files)
{
    if (!Session.GetIsLoggedIn())
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "User");

    var fileRequest = Session.CreateRequest<PAddFileRequest, bool>(); //Creates a business logic request
    fileRequest.Files.Add(...);
    var result = await Session.HandleRequestAsync(fileRequest); //Handles and executes a business logic request by checking authority

    if (result)
        return RedirectToAction("List");

    return RedirectToError();
}
```

And upload progress action is simple as below for now :) :

```
public ActionResult UploadProgress()
{
    //var saveProgressRequest = Session.CreateRequest<PSaveFileProgressInfoRequest, PSaveFileProgressInfoResponse>();
    //saveProgressRequest.ProgressHandle = progressHandle;
    //var response = Session.HandleRequest(saveProgressRequest);
    return Content("Test!");
}
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async` doesn't change the HTTP protocol. The `Upload` request is in progress until you return the result.

You're probably running into the ASP.NET session lock, which [ensures that multiple request handlers don't interfere with each other when reading/writing session state](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amitsh/archive/2007/08/01/why-i-cannot-execute-two-requests-from-the-same-session-simultaneously-for-an-asp-net-application.aspx). I believe that MVC always takes a write lock on the session state by default, preventing any other actions from executing simultaneously (in the same session).

You can override this behavior by specifying the [`SessionState` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.sessionstateattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) on your controller.

Comment: I tried SessionState now, and it worked. But what asynchronous actions for if I can't make asynchronous request from same client?

Comment: Asynchronous handlers allow your server to scale better; when they `await` an incomplete operation, they return the thread to the thread pool for other requests to use.